# Delaying messages from queue rabbitmq spring

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have a problem with delaying messages when sending them to rabbitmq consumer. I have set the x-delay header however the problem is that I want messages to be send at one sec-time distance to the consumer. But in the case of the application with this code, they are all sent at the same time but after 1 sec of starting the application. So how can I send them gradually with 1 sec time difference between each other?

```
  public void produce(Company company){
       // for (Company company:
       //      companies) {
            amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, routingkey, company, new MessagePostProcessor() {
                @Override
                public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
                    message.getMessageProperties().setHeader("x-delay",10000);
                    return message;
                }
            });
            System.out.println("Send msg = " + company);
       // }

      // amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, routingkey, company);

    }
```

In the main application I'm calling the produce method for each company from company list (also tried with for inside produce method, didn't work).

Comment: Do you mean that if you put 10 messages into the queue all at once, they'll arrive spaced evenly across 10 seconds? Is there a reason you can't include the delay on the consumer end, i.e. just don't pause for a second after consuming a message, regardless of whether there's another one waiting?